# Will I be able to get a quest for a dungeon already "cleared"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I stumble across a dungeon and clear it out, will this prevent any possible quests to that location?  Or will the activation of a quest repopulate the dungeon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my experience so far, either certain areas of the dungeon will be inaccessible until you accept the quest or you will be able to complete the quest as soon as it starts by way of having already obtained whatever the dungeon holds in store. So no, you won't prevent any possible quests to that location by clearing out dungeons.

As Dave notes, some quests require you to clear dungeons or kill bosses, in which case if you've already cleared the dungeon new enemies will spawn there that you have  to kill.

Comment: +1 I found a cave the other day with no (obvious) way of bypassing a gate after clearing several rooms before it.

Comment: `Oh, you mean this old thing?` *hands quest item found in depth of dungeon* -> quest finished in 2 seconds.

Comment: @Konerak Playing a thief character, this is the best feeling.

Comment: @Konerak I laughed my ass off when that happened to me.

Comment: There is a third possibility: You can also get "clear the dungeon"/"kill the boss" quests for dungeons you've already visited, in which case some new enemies will spawn there for you to go back and kill.

Comment: @DaveSherohman I've had this happen at least twice now

Answer (score 3):

there are some areas where you can clear the entire dungeon. When you get a quest to go there, if the quest doesn't involve getting something you may have already gotten, it will repopulate the dungeon, most of the time with enemies scaled to your level

Answer (score 1):

Some quests will pick from multiple dungeons as well. In this case, if one is cleared already, it will pick a different one